# Character jump sometimes stronger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2d side scroller platformer game, I have a issue where my character's jump force is not stable. Sometimes the character jumps the way I expected it to behave, but I think based on my observation there is an instance where my character's jump force is lower and higher. any one could help me and explain the soultion? thanks!

```
public bool isgrounded;
public float groundradius;
public Transform checkslot;
public LayerMask LM;
public float jumpower;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isgrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && myrb.velocity.y <= 0.0f)
    {
        isgrounded = false;
        jumping = true;
        myanim.SetBool("groundedanim", isgrounded);
        myrb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);


    }
    isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(checkslot.position, groundradius, LM);
    myanim.SetBool("groundedanim", isgrounded);
    myanim.SetFloat("verticalspeed", myrb.velocity.y);
```

ok I added this extra information, so does this `Dash` function that I have included in `FixedUpdate` affects my jumping physics? if so how can I fix this jumping issue that I currently have? ty.

```
public float dashspeed;
float dashtime;
public float startdash;
int direction;
public bool isleft;
public bool isRight;
public bool isClickDash;

void Start () {
    dashtime = startdash;
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
  Dash();
}

  public void Dash()
{
    if (direction == 0)
    {
        if (isleft)
        {
            direction = 1;
        }
        else if (isRight)
        {
            direction = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dashtime <= 0)
        {
            direction = 0;
            dashtime = startdash;
            myrb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            if (dashtime == startdash)
            {
                isClickDash = false;
                myanim.SetInteger("TriggerDash", 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dashtime -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (direction == 1)
            {
                if (isClickDash)
                {
                    DashNow();                                    
                }
            }
            else if (direction == 2)
            {
                if (isClickDash)
                {
                    DashNow();                                      
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public void DashNow()
{
    isClickDash = true;
    myanim.SetInteger("TriggerDash", 1);
    if (isRight)
    {
        myrb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashspeed;
    }
    else if (isleft)
    {
        myrb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashspeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think because you are using ForceMode2D Impulse, the force will depend on the mass of the rigidbody, try to do some logs and verify.

Comment: Is character's jump force still lower and higher if you disable `Dash()` function?

Comment: You should decide if you will manipulate your rigidbody by applying forces _or_ directly modifying its state (assignig a velocity or position value), but mixing both approachs is like asking for trouble.